# Typescript 'req.file' is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase-storage, multer

```
import express, { Router } from "express";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";
import multer from "multer";
import config from "/home/rizki/herbal66-laravel/express/firebase.config"

const router: Router = express.Router();

//Initialize a firebase application
initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Storage and get a reference to the service
const storage = getStorage();

// Setting up multer as a middleware to grab photo uploads
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

router.post("/", upload.single("filename"), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dateTime = giveCurrentDateTime();

        const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${req.file.originalname + "       " + dateTime}`);

        // Create file metadata including the content type
        const metadata = {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        };

        // Upload the file in the bucket storage
        const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, req.file.buffer, metadata);
        //by using uploadBytesResumable we can control the progress of uploading like pause, resume, cancel

        // Grab the public url
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);

        console.log('File successfully uploaded.');
        return res.send({
            message: 'file uploaded to firebase storage',
            name: req.file.originalname,
            type: req.file.mimetype,
            downloadURL: downloadURL
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
});

const giveCurrentDateTime = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    const dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
    return dateTime;
}

export default router;
```

**Got 5 error**
`const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${req.file.originalname + "       " + dateTime}`);`
` const metadata = {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        };`
 `const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, req.file.buffer, metadata);`
 `name: req.file.originalname,`
` type: req.file.mimetype,`

**I have installed some package, like :**
`npm i @types/express`
`npm install dotenv` 
`npm i @types/multer --save-dev`
`npm install typescript`

And still not working...

Comment: Can't reproduce it with `"multer": "^1.4.2"` and `"express": "^4.17.1",`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the type of data that is `req` in your input, with that TypeScript can know if req.file is valid or no.

You should add the type to `req` (and every other const or var that you can) like this:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("filename"), async (req: {file: File} , res) => {
```

Check the [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html) to see more about the type of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct [according to the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/multer/index.d.ts#L52). You can disable [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if you're not 100% positive it'll be defined, or use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) to tell TypeScript not to worry about it.